# Append the html table in another table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two tables and I want to merge the table so that it will appear adjacent to each other.

There are two rows in header and I want to append both rows in the body which I did.
But when I am trying to merge it next to each other, I can append only one row in header. I don't know how to add both rows in header.

Please find the code snippet below.

```js
 $('#joined thead tr').append($('#tbl1 thead tr').html()).append('<td></td>');
  $('#joined thead tr').append($('#tbl2 thead tr').html()).append('<td></td>');
  
$('#tbl1 tbody tr').append('<td></td>');
  $('#tbl1 tbody tr').each(function(index) {
    $('#joined tbody').append("<tr></tr>");
    $('#joined tbody tr').eq(index).append($('#tbl1 tbody tr').eq(index).html());
  });
 $('#tbl2 tbody tr').append('<td></td>');
  $('#tbl2 tbody tr').each(function(index) {
    $('#joined tbody').append("<tr></tr>");
    $('#joined tbody tr').eq(index).append($('#tbl2 tbody tr').eq(index).html());
  });
```

```css
#joined {
         background: #ff0;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="joined">
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
      <tbody>
</table>
<table id="tbl1">
  <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
  <tr><th colspan=3>Table 1</th></tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1595050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>4573200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1193328</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1193328</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="tbl2">
  <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
  <tr><th colspan=3>Table 2</th></tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #fff">Opportunity</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #fff">Pipeline Count</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #fff">Pipeline Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TEst</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1595050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEst</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>4573200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEst Submitted</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1193328</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been on the right way to use the function `eq()`. I have added the attribute `sources` to the target table to select the tables to merge.

**The code below is just to clarify the function and was created for exactly your example**

If you have multiple tables with different numbers of rows in the body, some data in the merged table will be missing. In this case you would still have to modify the code.

```js
mergeTables($('#joined'));

function mergeTables($joinedTable) {
  // If you want to keep the original tables, just delete the "detach()"
  var $tables = $($joinedTable.data('targets')).detach(),
    tableLength = $tables.length;

  if (tableLength == 0) {
    return;
  }

  var $currentTable, $theadRows, $tbodyRows;

  for (var i = 0; i < tableLength; i++) {
    $currentTable = $($tables[i]);

    if (i == 0) {
      fillTable($joinedTable, $currentTable);

      $theadRows = $joinedTable.find('thead tr');
      $tbodyRows = $joinedTable.find('tbody tr');

      continue;
    }

    appendTableHeader($theadRows, $currentTable);
    appendTableBody($tbodyRows, $currentTable);
  }
}

function fillTable($joinedTable, $currentTable) {
  $joinedTable.empty().append(
    $currentTable.find('thead').clone(),
    $currentTable.find('tbody').clone()
  );
}

function appendTableHeader($theadRows, $currentTable) {
  var $currentHeadRows = $currentTable.find('thead tr'),
    currentHeadRowLength = $currentHeadRows.length;

  for (var j = 0; j < currentHeadRowLength; j++) {
    $theadRows.eq(j).append($currentHeadRows[j].innerHTML);
  }
}

function appendTableBody($tbodyRows, $currentTable) {
  var $currentBodyRows = $currentTable.find('tbody tr'),
    currentBodyRowLength = $currentBodyRows.length;

  for (var j = 0; j < currentBodyRowLength; j++) {
    $tbodyRows.eq(j).append($currentBodyRows[j].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="joined" data-targets="#tbl1, #tbl2"></table>
<table id="tbl1">
  <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
    <tr>
      <th colspan=3>Table 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1595050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>4573200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1193328</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proposal Submitted</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1193328</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="tbl2">
  <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
    <tr>
      <th colspan=3>Table 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #fff">Opportunity</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #fff">Pipeline Count</th>
      <th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #fff">Pipeline Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TEst</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1595050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEst</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>4573200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEst Submitted</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1193328</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```